For which sets of functions can we establish $f$-mean inequality?
For a finite set $X \in \mathbb{R}$ and a bijective increasing function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, let's define the $f$-mean of $X$ as the following.
$$\mu_f(X) \equiv f^{-1} \left( \frac{1}{|X|} \sum_{x \in X} f(x) \right)$$
We have the mean inequalities like the AM-GM and the generalized mean inequality (although they are defined on positive real numbers) which handles special cases of $f$-means. For example, the geometric mean is the $\log$-mean. But not all combinations of $f$ makes it possible for an inequality to hold.
So I got curious about the minimal condition for a set of functions $S$ where exists an order relation such that if $f,g \in S$ and $f\leq g$ then $\mu_f(X)\leq\mu_g(X)$ for arbitrary $X$.
My attempt:
Because of bijectivity and Jensen's inequality, I found out that any $f,g\in S$ should satisfy that $fg^{-1}$ is either convex or concave. So, assuming the second derivatives exist and the first derivatives are never $0$, I took the second derivative of $fg^{-1}$. The result was that always
$$\frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)} \leq \frac{g''(x)}{g'(x)}$$
or the other way around. This suggests that ${f''(x)}/{f'(x)}$ is ordered well on $\mathbb{R}$ for all $f \in S$ for every $x$. I think it's too abstract, but I'm not sure if it can be clarified further.
Also, I don't have much clue on the case where the derivatives do not exist.
This is not really a definite question, so any ideas on the properties of $S$ would be great help!

Let me denote the order relation
$$ f\leqq g\iff \mu_f(X)\leq\mu_f(Y)\;\forall |X|<\infty,\;X\subset \mathbb R.$$
Let $\mathcal H^+$ be the set of bijective increasing functions on $\mathbb R$. It is easy to see that this is precisely the set of all increasing homeomorphisms of $\mathbb R$. On this set, it definitely holds
$$ f\leqq g \iff g\circ f^{-1}\text{ is convex}. $$
Recall that every continuous function has a distributional derivative, and since any $f\in \mathcal H^+$ is increasing, the derivative is a non-negative Radon measure on $\mathbb R$.
If in addition we have that $f$ and $g$ are $C^1$ with $C^1$ inverse, the derivative of $g\circ f^{-1}$ is
$$ (g\circ f^{-1})’=(\frac{g’}{f’})\circ g^{-1}. $$
Hence, the condition $f\leqq g$ is equivalent to
$$ \frac{g’}{f’}\text{ is non-decreasing}. $$
This suggests that for general functions $f,g\in \mathcal H^+$, $f\leqq g$ is equivalent to
$$ g’ \text{is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $f’$ with $dg’=h\cdot df’$}\quad\text{and}\quad h \text{ is non-decreasing}. $$
I am talking about absolute continuity of measures, and $h$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $g’$ w.r.t. the measure $f’$. I don’t know if this is true, but I have the impression that somehing like this can be proved.
Even if the above was true, this condition is not so easy to handle, since $h$ is defined $f’$-a.e. (keep in mind that $f’$ is a measure, which can be singular with respect to the Lebesgue measure). But, for example, this would say that for non-regular functions, $f\leqq g$ implies that $g’$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $f’$. So, a set $S$ on which $\leqq$ is a total order cannot contain two functions with derivatives that are mutually singular like, say,
$$f(x)=x+c(x),\qquad g(x)=x+c(x-1),$$
where $c$ is the Devil’s staircase extended to $\mathbb R$ as $0$ for $x<0$ and $1$ for $x>1$. A clearer example even if less extreme would be
$$ f(x)=x^{1/3},\qquad g(x)=(x-1)^{1/3}, $$ although their derivatives are still absolutely continuous w.r.t. each other: each one blows up where the other one is bounded, so it cannot hold $f\leqq g$ or $g\leqq f$.
